# What are the implications of enabling trace flag 1222 - write deadlock information to the log?

Tags: sql-server, database-deadlocks, dbcc

```
DBCC TRACEON (1222) -- writes deadlocks to the errorlog
```

has anyone monitored if having this trace flag enabled would increase any WAIT_TYPE in particular or accrue any performance problem in any situation?

For this question, let's consider that there are not many deadlocks, only occasionally.

Comment: sql server does lots of logging out of the box so I can't see that having this flag turned on will cause any issues. this might be a relevant read: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2130/finding-sql-server-deadlocks-using-trace-flag-1222/

Comment: @Tanner, thanks Tanner - good article

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on many things I have heard around I currently have the following opinion:

There is very little overhead in enabling the trace flag unless you’re experiencing lots of deadlocks, which would cause a large amount of deadlock graphs to be written to the error log.  However, it doesn’t sound like this is the case so it should be safe to enable the trace (it can always be turned off at any point with an instance restart).